# How to use openapi3 json specification to validate if Express application has set up correct routes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, code-generation, openapi

## Summary

I use [orval](https://orval.dev/) to generate frontend code in order to fetch data from the backend. The API specification is using the openapi 3 format.

**I want to be able to automatically validate if my express backend is implementing the correct endpoints by comparing the specification with the actual implementation.**

## Example

Let's assume that this is the specification `api.json`:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "My Service"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://my.service.com/api"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/my-endpoint": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "List all things",
        "operationId": "listThings",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Thing"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "description": "unexpected error",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Error"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Thing": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Error": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "code",
          "message"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Orval generates frontend code to fetch defined endpoints via `axios` and the according Typescript interfaces for request and response data.

*So far so good.*

## Problem

My express backend does not know about the openapi specification. I need to manually create the correct express endpoints and make sure that they return the correct HTTP codes, correct response types and correct error handling.

I learned there are code generators like [swagger-routes-express](https://github.com/davesag/swagger-routes-express), but my concern with those is that they hide the endpoint definition and that it could be difficult to implement extra business logic to those endpoints. I may be wrong here, but i still didn't get how that would work in this scenario.

## Desired solution

I think there are two variants that would be a great outcome:

1. A code generator that parses the `api.json` above and generates correct endpoints with proper Typescript types. It needs to be able to accept custom code in those endpoints which shouldn't be overwritten the next time the specification changes and code is regenerated.
2. A linter that checks the code if the correct endpoints exist and have the correct request and response types. Maybe a set of eslint rules.

Is there anything out there i could use for this?

Comment: This would probably be closed as it is requesting suggestions for libraries/tools. That being said, I doubt there is anything out there that can meet your criteria, especially if you need custom code/handling injected. Many frameworks do the opposite of what you are doing. The code in the API including the types used for input/output is used to generate the swagger/openapi document so that it always stays in sync with what the api actually does. An example would be [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction).

Comment: Also, even if a tool could generate robust endpoints, it wouldn't ever really be able to know how to connect to your database, handle CRUD operations, business logic of transforming/projecting data form the database to the final output, interact with remote APIs, integration/unit testing, caching. In terms of testing the output, there are tools such as [dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd) that can test APIs against swagger/openapi documents.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks for your input. As far as i understood, the tooling does not need to know anything about databases, business logic or transforming data. It just needs to check the defined paths, methods and typescript types for request input and the return type of `res.send()`.

What I actually want is single source of truth. One definition of the API that is then used to validate if BE and FE are implementing the correct paths at least. At compile-time.

Comment: Then you could try something like `dredd` which takes the swagger/openapi as the input and can make requests against a locally running API instance and can validate output matches the schema in the swagger/openapi and can also check for different status codes. It could at least get you one step forward.

Comment: Yes, definitely a step forward, but i would like to have compile-time control over that instead of running the backend.

Comment: What an endpoint says it will output (typescript type/schema) can be different than what it actually outputs when running right? How would you account for that? Anyways, I do hope you find a tool that can do all of this or you end up building one from scratch, could be pretty neat.

Comment: Found something that comes close enough to what i want to do: https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator